# Error when calling low-level function over JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm writing Java bindings to a closed-source data-acquisition library (written in C) that sets up DMA and interfaces with a PCIe card installed on the PC.

The C library has straightforward initialize function. It returns 0 if there's no error:

```
int InitPanel();
```

When I call that function in my C++ project, it works just fine.

```
int main()
{
   // errorCode is 0 after this function call.
   int errorCode = InitPanel();
   std::cout << "ErrorCode: " << errorCode << std::endl;
}
```

So I made that C++ project a DLL that has JNI bindings to that function, so I can call it from Java:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_DataAcquisition_Init(JNIEnv* env, jclass cla)
{
   return InitPanel();
}
```

Java has no issues calling that function, but for some reason InitPanel is returning an error code when it's called from Java. The error is an unhelpful "Cannot initialize panel".

- Both the Java runtime and C library are 64 bit: I even tested passing -d64 to the VM.
- There's no "Unsatisfied Link Error" at all; the C library seems to have all its required dependencies in both cases.
- It doesn't seem to be a permission error; I've tested disabling UAC, firewall, etc.
- I've tried raising the Java VM memory (via Xms/Xmx) incase perhaps it was restricting the max memory of the process.

What other possible things could it be?

Comment: Different working directory?

Comment: What OS are you running on?  What version of Java?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Win10Pro, Java 1.8.0_131, 64bit

Comment: This is kind of squishy; we don't have much to go on.  However, you shoudl know that if you have the source code and .pdb for the C library, you can attach to it with a native debugger, set a function breakpoint, and step through the C function.